# Youtube Analytics API - Can't get total views by channel

Tags: youtube-api

I can get content owner report from this tesing url below (section Try it)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/

> ids = contentOwner=={MycontentOwner}
>
> start-date = 2013-05-01
>
> end-date = 2013-05-31
>
> metrics = views
>
> dimensions = day
>
> filters = claimedStatus==claimed
>
> sort = day

But I can't get report by channel

> ids = channel=={**Mychannel**}
>
> start-date = 2013-05-01
>
> end-date = 2013-05-31
>
> metrics = views
>
> dimensions = day
>
> sort = day

Get error below.

> 400 Bad Request 
>   - Show headers 
>   -  { "error": {  "errors": [   {    "domain": "global",    "reason": "invalid",    "message": "Invalid value (**Mychannel**) given in field parameters.ids."   }  ],  "code": 400,  "message": "Invalid value (**Mychannel**) given in field parameters.ids." }}

**content owner** is name that show on cms , **channel** is user name on youtube website. right?

On youtube analytics report, there is **Mychannel** in Content Owner account . But why I can't get data from **Mychannel** via tesing url (section Try it)?

Edit:

I think ,I knew it. channel==CHANNEL_ID, where CHANNEL_ID specifies the unique channel ID for your channel. The value is currently a string that begins with the letters UC, though its format is subject to change. (You can retrieve your channel's ID using the YouTube Data API's channels.list method.)

I have another way to get channel report.

> ids = contentOwner=={MycontentOwner}
>
> filter = channel=**MychannelID**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for your channels list using the following code:

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({ 
    mine: 'true', 
    part: 'contentDetails,id', 
    metrics: 'views,comments,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,likes,dislikes,shares' 
});
```